# Package name and its effect on search results for Android-- My app has vanished

Tags: android, google-play

Direct question so you don't have to read the backstory if you don't want to:

> My question is, how much of a roll does the package name and/or contents of the manifest effect search ranking? What else could be the problem if not these?

**Backstory:**

I released my first Android app recently under a specific name relating to the app's very simple function. After a few short days I achieved 100 downloads and decided to release a more general version of the app with more features, so I changed the name accordingly. I have a bit of an SEO background so in both cases so I made sure to include keywords in the title of the app as well as the description. The problem is, after releasing version 2.0 under a new name it has completely gone off the radar. The only way to get to it is by typing in the full name, and as a result, I have not seen very many downloads. I am surprised the 1 person per day installing my app is even finding it. When I had version 1.0 on the Play store I could search for any related keyword and see my app near the top of the results.

I suspect that the package name may play a roll this situation, since my package name was the main keyword for my initial app idea, and I cannot change the package name otherwise it will be considered a new app.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I still don't know what caused the drop in ranking, but I assume it is due to competition. I re-released the app with a different package and APK and still did not see any downloads. On the other hand, I simply changed the name of the original app back to the specific niche name and it shot up in ranking. I am now getting a consistent stream of downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Search your app in Appbrain Apptimizer. It helps you to improve your search ranking. The play store's ranking system is pretty unconventional. You need downloads + description length + ratings and many more things which I may never know.

Comment: That seems like a great idea, except my app doesn't appear on Apptimizer-- very few in my niche do. Is that normal? When I try to direct link it (http://www.appbrain.com/apptimizer/search-term/com.mycompany.package) it can't find it.